# AutoCAD .NET: Filling a Region with a grid / custom hatch

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2012, autocad-plugin

I want to fill a selected region with a custom hatch that looks like a grid (like a chess table). I tried to use the ANSI37 pattern but its lines are too dense and I could not modify anything visually except the angle of the hatch. Also, I tried the custom hatch pattern creation of autocad but loading the file in autocad or creating a hatch from it in my code always results in error.
This is my question: Is there anyway I can create a custom hatch pattern (grid like) that I can control the distance of lines of the grid? Is it possible for me to retrieve the custom hatch object later then query info of its lines? (how many lines, start points and end points, distance between them...)
?
 Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 0):

1. About customize the predefined hatch pattern: It is possible to do that, however the properties of the hatch must be defined in a certain order to have actual effect, or else it will be ignored and use the default value instead.

for example: in my case, I defined the value of HatchStyle before PatternScale and PatternSpace while it should be the other way around. Thus, I receive the result from the default values.

2. About the custom grid lines drawing and querying: I got some ideas from these:

http://adndevblog.typepad.com/autocad/2013/07/create-hatch-objects-using-trace-boundaries-using-net.html

using the Editor.TraceBoudary() method, I can retrieve the loops I needed with the outer most loop will be the last entry in the return DBObjectCollection (a Polyline object to be precise). Then, create the region that needed to be hatched and access its RegionAreaProperty.Extends to get the bottom-left and top-right point of the rectangle that contains my newly created region. After that
, I can implement my logic to draw the lines of the grid.

Note that this method only works on 2d loops ( regions, closed polylines, lines, curves... on Oxy plane). I haven't find a way for the Editor.TraceBoundary() to work with 3d loops yet.

3. Still open for advices and suggestion for 3d loops and creating custom hatch from a given HatchPattern object.